# A triangle not being plotted

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

I have the code for a triangle on the Cartesian plane.  There seems to be two commands that `TikZ` is not able to compile.  The first line is `\addplot[samples=501,dashed,domain=1:3] {3,x};` which should instruct `pgfplots` to draw a vertical line segment for the altitude of the triangle. The second line is `\tkzMarkRightAngle(A,P,B);` which should instruct `TikZ` to draw the right angle mark at the base of the altitude.  (I put a `%` in front of these lines so that the code would compile.)

```
\documentclass[10pt]{amsart}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,angles,positioning,intersections,quotes,decorations.markings}
\usepackage{mathtools,systeme,array}

\usepackage{tkz-euclide}
\usetkzobj{all}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.11}


\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[width=6in,axis equal image,clip=false,
    axis lines=middle,
    xmin=-3,xmax=5,samples=501,
    xlabel=$x$,ylabel=$y$,
    ymin=-3,ymax=3,
    restrict y to domain=-3:3,
    enlargelimits={abs=0.25cm},
    axis line style={latex-latex},
    ticklabel style={font=\tiny,fill=white},
    xtick={\empty},ytick={\empty},
    xlabel style={at={(ticklabel* cs:1)},anchor=north west},
    ylabel style={at={(ticklabel* cs:1)},anchor=south west}
]
\addplot[samples=501,domain=-2:3,blue] {0.4*x + 1.8};
\addplot[samples=501,domain=3:4,blue] {-2*x + 9};
\addplot[samples=501,domain=-2:4,blue] {1};
%\addplot[samples=501,dashed,domain=1:3] {3,x};
\end{axis}
(-2,1)node[label=left:$A$](A){};
(3,3)node[label=above right:$B$](B){};
(4,1)node[label=right:$C$](C){};
(3,1)node(P){};
%\tkzMarkRightAngle(A,P,B);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: For your first question, replace the `\addplot` line with `\draw[dashed] (axis cs:3,1) -- (axis cs:3,3)`.

Comment: @Paul Gessler  Why is the `addplopt` command not being compiled?  I have used this command in many other diagrams to draw vertical lines.

Comment: I'd like to see an example of that working, because it's really not designed to work that way at all... For one thing, the contents inside the curly braces are supposed to be one expression defining y in terms of x, not a parametric definition of x- and y-coordinates as you're attempting here.

Comment: @Paul Gessler  Look for `Using the \draw command to plot a vertical line` at this web site.  I just posted the code.

Comment: OK, but a hyperlink would have been much easier. Your posting there is _not_ the same thing you're doing here. Take note of the difference between `(6,x)` and `{3,x}`. The choice of parentheses vs. braces is significant because it puts `pgfplots` in different "modes", if you will.

Comment: @Paul Gessler  I made the necessary edit in my code - replacing the braces with parentheses.  Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first question was solved in the comments: replacing `{3,x}` with `(3,x)` allows the vertical line to be plotted in a more elegant way than the `\draw[dashed] (axis cs:3,1) -- (axis cs:3,3);` which I originally suggested. However, why draw 501 samples of the line when 2 will do? I've edited this in the code below.

The second question is solved by recognizing that the `tkz-euclide` macros expect to operate on TikZ `coordinate`s rather than `node`s. I also moved these inside the `axis` environment to use `axis cs` to place the coordinates appropriately.

```
\documentclass[10pt]{amsart}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,angles,positioning,intersections,quotes,decorations.markings}
\usepackage{mathtools,systeme,array}

\usepackage{tkz-euclide}
\usetkzobj{all}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.11}


\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[width=6in,axis equal image,clip=false,
    axis lines=middle,
    xmin=-3,xmax=5,samples=501,
    xlabel=$x$,ylabel=$y$,
    ymin=-3,ymax=3,
    restrict y to domain=-3:3,
    enlargelimits={abs=0.25cm},
    axis line style={latex-latex},
    ticklabel style={font=\tiny,fill=white},
    xtick={\empty},ytick={\empty},
    xlabel style={at={(ticklabel* cs:1)},anchor=north west},
    ylabel style={at={(ticklabel* cs:1)},anchor=south west}
]
\addplot[samples=501,domain=-2:3,blue] {0.4*x + 1.8};
\addplot[samples=501,domain=3:4,blue] {-2*x + 9};
\addplot[samples=501,domain=-2:4,blue] {1};
\addplot[samples=2,dashed,domain=1:3] (3,x); % solved in the comments to the question
\coordinate (P) at (axis cs:3,1);
\coordinate[label=left:$A$] (A) at (axis cs:-2,1);
\coordinate[label=above right:$B$] (B) at (axis cs:3,3);
\coordinate[label=right:$C$] (C) at (axis cs:4,1);
\end{axis}
\tkzMarkRightAngle(A,P,B);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This is the diagram that I wanted.  Thanks.  For the code, I would like to have `(3,1)coordinate(P);` and
`(-2,1)coordinate(A)node[left]{$A$};` outside the axis environment.  The coordinates are filed in memory correctly, but the placement of the labels for the vertices are not displayed properly.  What is the code to have "A" displayed to the left of the vertex at (-2,1) and to have "B" displayed to the "above right" of (3,3)?

Comment: @Adelyn I'm not sure what your question is asking. The labels are already where you want them, are they not?

Comment: Yes, they are where I wanted them.  I am interested in putting the commands for the vertices and the labels for the vertices outside the axis environment.  That is the reason that I use different commands: `(-2,1) coordinate (A) node[left]{$A$};` and `(3,3) coordinate (B) node[left]{$B$};` and `(3,1) coordinate (P);`.  These may not be quite right, as I had suggested. I get an error message with the code `\tkzMarkRightAngle(A,P,B);`.  It says "no shape P found."

Comment: @Adelyn, I don't understand. The commands you have don't work. The commands I have provided do. Why do you want to change back to the ones that don't work? The commands must be inside of the `axis` environment in order to have access to that coordinate system (which may change with scaling, axis size, etc.).

Comment: I would like to get familiar with `TikZ` commands, too.  For example, the following code also gives me the picture that I want (without the axes).

Comment: `\begin{tikzpicture}
\path (-2,1) coordinate (A) (3,3) coordinate (B) (4,1) coordinate (C);
\draw (A)
-- (B) node [at start, left]{$A$}
-- (C) node [at start, above right]{$B$}
-- (A) node [at start, right]{$C$}
-- cycle;
\end{tikzpicture}`

Comment: @Adelyn, `\coordinate` in my code _is_ a TikZ command... But again, it has to be placed inside the `axis` environment in order to have access to that coordinate system.

Comment: What I would like to do, just to get familiar with coding in `TikZ` is to declare and label the three coordinates of the vertices of the triangle on three separate lines of code, declare the coordinates of the foot of an altitude of the triangle on another line of code, and use a command like `\tkzMarkRightAngle(A,P,B);` to have a right angle mark displayed.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/20006/discussion-between-paul-gessler-and-adelyn).

Comment: Sure.  How do I get there?  I tried the link and it wouldn't let me get on.  (I am expecting a phone call in 5 minutes that I have to take.)